# Error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'

Tags: python

I am making a recommendation system with the surprise class, to know which type of parameter best suits my algorithm I am using the GridSearchCV class, so as not to pass the same parameters again, I have taken another csv file that is very similar to the training_set that I have used , but I get this:

I'm working with Jupiter Nootebook

```
data = pd.read_csv('datasets/Ratings.csv')

data.columns
Index(['User-ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating'], dtype='object')

gs = GridSearchCV(SVD, param_grid, measures=['rmse','mae'], cv=3)
gs.fit(data)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
  1 gs = GridSearchCV(SVD, param_grid, measures=['rmse','mae'], cv=3)
```

----> 2 gs.fit(data)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning_udemy\Lib\site-packages\surprise\model_selection    \search.py:100, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, data)
85     raise ValueError(
86         "refit cannot be used when data has been "
87         "loaded with load_from_folds()."
88     )
90 cv = get_cv(self.cv)
92 delayed_list = (
93     delayed(fit_and_score)(
94         self.algo_class(**params),
95         trainset,
96         testset,
97         self.measures,
98         self.return_train_measures,
99     )
--> 100     for params, (trainset, testset) in product(
101         self.param_combinations, cv.split(data)
102     )
103 )
104 out = Parallel(
105     n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
106     pre_dispatch=self.pre_dispatch,
107     verbose=self.joblib_verbose,
108 )(delayed_list)
110 (test_measures_dicts, train_measures_dicts, fit_times, test_times) = zip(*out)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning_udemy\Lib\site-packages\surprise\model_selection\split.py:92, in KFold.split(self, data)
81 def split(self, data):
82     """Generator function to iterate over trainsets and testsets.
83
84     Args:
(...)
89         tuple of (trainset, testset)
90     """
---> 92     if self.n_splits > len(data.raw_ratings) or self.n_splits < 2:
93         raise ValueError(
94             "Incorrect value for n_splits={}. "
95             "Must be >=2 and less than the number "
96             "of ratings".format(len(data.raw_ratings))
97         )
99     # We use indices to avoid shuffling the original data.raw_ratings list.

```
File ~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning_udemy\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5989, in   NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
5982 if (
5983     name not in self._internal_names_set
5984     and name not in self._metadata
5985     and name not in self._accessors
5986     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
5987 ):
5988     return self[name]
-> 5989 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'
```

I can't find where the error can come from, since it's the same file, but the file I used for the training_set is shortened by size, so there are many fewer examples.

I need help as i am a bit stuck and i want to check this code as the rmse and mae give me very high values ​​and i need to adjust the algorithm

Comment: It seems to me that you dont pass the dataframe to  GridsearchCV but a variable called SVD... If that is a dimension-reduced version of your data, you simply lost the columns due to this reduction?

Also, we cannot really se whats going on here, you should print your variables somehow since there are some sort of column mismatches that we cannot see "from remote"